# Is there a rule of thumb when porting iPhone graphics to Android?

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface, resolution, porting

I'd like to port my iPhone app to Android. The interface is constructed with artwork designed for 320x480 resolution. What steps do I need to take when I'm constructing the XML interface for the Android so that my GUI will be compatible with the different screen sizes (or at least the most popular ones...)?

Comment: What is your target android platform?

Comment: @Rpond, Charles is actually asking for the most popular Andriod screen resolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://d.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article. Basically, you will do one of the following for each of your graphics:

- Convert it to a 9-patch (see [this](http://d.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) and [this](http://d.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html)), or
- Create `ldpi`, `mdpi` and `hdpi` versions of it (this is detailed in the article linked above).

You should also read the [UI Guidelines](http://d.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html).